# NGINX gzip per virtualhost?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I know here are a lot of "similar" Q's, but anyway...

So – I have a `nginx.conf` with `gzip on;`. It's a new, clean Linux server, nothing yet done here.

Using `curl` – I can see `gzip` enabled:

```
$ curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" gzip.setevoy.kiev.ua/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 14:26:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 13:56:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: W/"5ba25593-264"
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Now – I'm adding simple config `conf.d/gzip.setevoy.kiev.ua.conf`:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name gzip.setevoy.kiev.ua;

    root /var/www/etag;
    index index.html;
}
```

And now – no `gzip` enabled:

```
$ curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" gzip.setevoy.kiev.ua/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 14:28:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 7
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 13:58:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5ba25616-7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Adding `gzip on;` directly to the `conf.d/gzip.setevoy.kiev.ua.conf` didn't help. Same if set `gzip off;` in the `nginx.conf` and `gzip on;` to the virtualhost's conf.

What I'm doing wrong here?

P.S. `gzip_vary on;`, `gzip_types *` etc., didn't help either.

Comment: IMO this is worth leaving open because it's a good catch on a subtle problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, that was simple - but I wasted a lot of time trying to figure it out. Maybe will be helpful for somebody else.

Everything was good with configs, but let's take a look on to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_min_length):

> Syntax:   gzip_min_length length; 
>   Default: gzip_min_length 20;

And guess what? I tested it with `index.html` with one word added... Obviously, its size was < 20 bytes so NGINX didn't apply `gzip` on it.

So I just added `gzip_min_length 0;` to the `nginx.conf` - and all works now.